# how to align two fixed divs? example live-chat and cookie law agreement

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have 2 fixed divs (live chat & cookie law agreement) and I want if cookie law is accepted, live-chat div move down. There is some simple CSS solution for that? Or any other solution, because right now live-chat is on top and hiding text. I want both visible, but not in the middle of the screen. Thanks for ideas.

[image]

Comment: Please share your code. I think it's because of floating issue.

Comment: take a look at the code https://www.safesex.lt/

Comment: are you tried the chat div z-index `999998` to `999999`

Comment: i tried, it would be simple too simple solution. but as you can see it cover text.

Comment: change the background opacity of chat, then it will visible the text. :)

Answer (score 0):

remove index from `#cookieNotice`

```
#cookieNotice {
    z-index: 999999 !important; 
}
```

may it works for you

Comment: I tried, it would be a too easy too simple solution. but as you can see it cover text.

Comment: then place your cokiee div at end after the `<main/>` section and remove `position: fixed;` from cookie div.